# Error was detected while a C++MEX interface was running which crashed Matlab although compiling was successful?

Tags: c++, matlab, crash, mex

I am wrapping a C++ code into Matlab by using mex C++ interface. Although compiling was successful, Matlab crashes when running the function in the code and I do not what is causing it! I am using Matlab 2019a, and I am using the following code

```
#include "mex.hpp"
#include "mexAdapter.hpp"
#include "RBergomi.h"
using namespace matlab::mex;
using namespace matlab::data;

class MexFunction : public matlab::mex::Function {
public:
        void operator()(matlab::mex::ArgumentList outputs, matlab::mex::ArgumentList inputs) {
             Vector H(1); 
             H= Vector { 0.07};
             Vector eta(1);
             eta= Vector { 1.9};
             Vector rho(1) ;
             rho= Vector { -0.9};
             Vector T(1) ;
             T = Vector { 1.0};
             Vector K(1) ;
             K= Vector { 1.0 };
             double xi = 0.0552;
             int  N = 2;
             long M = 1;
    
             Vector W1(2); 
             W1= Vector { 1.0, 0.0};
             Vector W1perp(2); 
             W1perp = Vector { 1.0 ,0.0};
             RBergomiST Obj=RBergomiST(xi, H, eta, rho, T, K, N, M);
             double RB;
             price(RB,  Obj, W1, W1perp );
             outputs[0][0] = RB;
         }      
         void price(double RB,  RBergomiST  Obj,  const Vector& W1, const Vector& W1perp) {
               RB=Obj.ComputePayoffRT_single(W1,  W1perp);
         }

};
```

For compiling I did

```
mex -g  Bergomi_interface.cpp -lfftw3 RBergomi.cpp ParamTot.cpp BlackScholes.cpp
```

which went successfully but I have the crash of Matlab and this message when running it.

I tried to check if I have a memory leak with Valgrind and I got this final output after fixing  some memory leaks but still Matlab crashes.

> ==6751== Memcheck, a memory error detector
>
> ==6751== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
>
> ==6751== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
>
> ==6751== Command: ./RBergomi
>
> ==6751==
>
> ==6751==
>
> ==6751== HEAP SUMMARY:
>
> ==6751==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
>
> ==6751==   total heap usage: 1,455 allocs, 1,454 frees, 368,936 bytes allocated
>
> ==6751==
>
> ==6751== 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
>
> ==6751==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-
>
> amd64->linux.so)
>
> ==6751==    by 0x52C1EFF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-
>
> gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
>
> ==6751==    by 0x40106C9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
>
> ==6751==    by 0x40107DA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
>
> ==6751==    by 0x40107DA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
>
> ==6751==    by 0x4000C69: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
>
> ==6751==
>
> ==6751== LEAK SUMMARY:
>
> ==6751==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==6751==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==6751==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==6751==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
>
> ==6751==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==6751==
>
> ==6751== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
>
> ==6751== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Comment: Any runtime error will cause it. E.g. an out of bounds memory read

Comment: If that is the case how can I control in matlab? I was using this code before with C++ and python and had no issues of memory!!

Comment: Python and matlab error very differently. Sometimes one can recover in situations where the other one can not. The only option is writting code that does not error, so neither needs to recover. There is nothing to control, simply your code is erroring, but MATLAB does not know how to recover from a segfault and crashes. This is the most likely case anyway

Comment: I checked through my system and it does not seem an issue of memory!

Comment: I did not say it was memory, I said its likely a run time error. A possible cause of a runtime error is caused by bad memory operations. There are infinite other causes.

Comment: "I checked through my system and it does not seem an issue of memory!" Your system cannot tell if you write out of bounds and overwrite something important in the MATLAB kernel, or if you try to read or write from a bit of memory that does not belong to your process. Both of these actions would crash MATLAB. The only way to tell is to run your MEX-file through a tool like Valgrind, which checks every memory access in your code while the code is running. In any case, the code you posted is not sufficient to guess at the problem. Read [mcve], and try to create one to post here.

Comment: The one thing I can point at is that your function `price` takes `RB` by value, and hence where you call this function, the variable `RB` will not be set. I recommend that you start with a basic tutorial on C++ before attempting to put together a MEX-file.

Comment: Many thanks @Chris Luengo for your comments. I run valgrind and I had 3 errors of memory when using fftw in my code. Now after fixing them I got 0 error with Valgrind but still Matlab crushes. At the end of my question you find the new output with Valgrind.

Comment: (If you want me to be notified of your comments, you need to spell my name right) You are memchecking `./RBergomi`. That is not MATLAB running the MEX-file. The issue is likely in the interface between MATLAB and the function you're callling. It is likely writing in an array that has not been allocated or something like that. Also, memory leaks are irrelevant (they should be fixed, but don't cause crashes).

Comment: Many thanks @Cris Luengo and sorry for the misspelling!

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the C++ interface, but maybe you need one less level of indirection on the outputs assignment since outputs[0] hasn't been created yet.  E.g., outputs[0] = RB. (Assuming you have fixed the assignment of RB per Chris's comment)